# Mock classes for every test class,only class scope

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

Im trying to mock classes inside a autowired class,at first we used @TestConfiguration for this purpose but this mock classes for EVERY test class,having hidden modifications in every test we have.
How can i mock the next scenario whitout affecting the other tests.

I have ServiceA(ServiceB,ServiceC)

ServiceA is the class which contains the method to tests
ServiceB is a class that should be mocked.
ServiceC is a class that should be the real class.

```
@Autowired
ServiceA serviceA;
@Mock
ServiceB serviceB;
```

This is what we tried with other choices,but seems @Mock is not working,just @MockBean does similar to @TestConfiguration but it does for every test class...

Comment: Maybe use @DirtiesContext to re-load context?

Comment: Reconsider the use of `@SpringBootTest`... You want a unit test **not** an integration test. Create an instance yourself (or let Mockito do it) and mock what you want. Don't shoehorn this into an `@SpringBootTest` when it can and should be a proper simple unit test. Also `@MockBean` doesn't do it for **every test class** only for the class ad-hand (or the classes that use the same `@MockBean`) and as such is different from an `@TestConfiguration`.